# Add circle with co-ordinate with text over the rendered shape in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

**This is the RoofShape class**

```
    package com.view9.stoddart.opengl;

    import android.opengl.GLU;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.view9.stoddart.model.OpenGlPointObject;
    import com.view9.stoddart.model.OpenGlRoofObject;

    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.ByteOrder;
    import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
    import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

    /**
     * Created by view9 on 10/25/15.
     */
    public class RoofShape {
        ArrayList<CoOrdinatesModel> cordinateList;
        List<Short> indicesList;

        private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer = null;
        private ShortBuffer mShapeBorderIndicesBuffer = null;
        private int mNumOfShapeBorderIndices = 0;
        OpenGlRoofObject roofObject;

        public RoofShape(OpenGlRoofObject roofObject) {
            this.roofObject = roofObject;
            setAllBuffers();
        }

        public void drawShape(GL10 gl) {
    //        Log.d("#####", "draw called");

            // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
            // coordinates to use when rendering.
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);

            // Draw all lines
            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, mNumOfShapeBorderIndices,
                    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mShapeBorderIndicesBuffer);
            GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    //        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        }

        private void setAllBuffers() {
            cordinateList = new ArrayList<>();

            cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(Float.parseFloat("0.0"), Float.parseFloat("0.0"), Float.parseFloat("0.0")));
            for (int pointCount = 0; pointCount < roofObject.getPoinstList().size(); pointCount++) {
                OpenGlPointObject pointObject = roofObject.getPoinstList().get(pointCount);
                cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(pointObject.getxAsis(), pointObject.getyAxis(), pointObject.getzAxis()));
            }

    /**====================================
     * working with the indices for line join
     * adding cordinates to indicesList
     ======================================*/
            indicesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int indicesCount = 0; indicesCount < roofObject.getLinesList().size(); indicesCount++) {
                String p = roofObject.getLinesList().get(indicesCount).getPath();
                for (String strPoint : p.split(",")) {
                    //spliting the string and eleminating the prefix string
                    String prefixStringEleminating = strPoint.substring(1);
                    Short intPoint = Short.parseShort(prefixStringEleminating);
                    indicesList.add(intPoint);
                }
            }

            updateVertexListToArray(cordinateList);
            updateVerticesListToArray(indicesList);
        }

        private void updateVerticesListToArray(List<Short> list) {
            /**
             * For converting indices list to indices array
             */
            ArrayList<Short> indicesList = new ArrayList<>();
            indicesList.addAll(list);
            short[] pointsToJoinList = new short[indicesList.size()];
            int indicesCount = 0;
            for (short shortIndices : indicesList) {
                pointsToJoinList[indicesCount++] = shortIndices;
            }

            mNumOfShapeBorderIndices = pointsToJoinList.length;
            ByteBuffer tbibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pointsToJoinList.length * 2);
            tbibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mShapeBorderIndicesBuffer = tbibb.asShortBuffer();
            mShapeBorderIndicesBuffer.put(pointsToJoinList);
            mShapeBorderIndicesBuffer.position(0);
        }

        private void updateVertexListToArray(ArrayList<CoOrdinatesModel> cordinateList) {
            /**============================
             * working with the vertexes
             * adding cordinates to VertexList
             ===============================*/
            List<Float> vList = new ArrayList<>();
            int loopSize = cordinateList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < loopSize; i++) {
                vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getxAxis());
                vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getyAxis());
                vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getzAxis());
            }
    /**
     * converting vertex list to array
     */
            float[] vertexlist = new float[vList.size()];
            int count = 0;
            for (float f : vList) {
                vertexlist[count++] = f;
            }

            ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexlist.length * 4);
            vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
            mVertexBuffer.put(vertexlist);
            mVertexBuffer.position(0);
        }

        public void setFlashingPointTOCordinatelist(GL10 gl, ArrayList<CoOrdinatesModel> flashingPoint) {
            cordinateList.addAll(flashingPoint);

            mVertexBuffer.clear();
            mShapeBorderIndicesBuffer.clear();

            updateVertexListToArray(cordinateList);
            Short initialPoint = Short.parseShort("0");
            Short previousUpdated = Short.parseShort("0");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                String totalNo = (cordinateList.size() + 1) + i + "";
                Short indice = Short.parseShort(totalNo);


                String str = indice + "";
                if (i == 1) {
                    indicesList.add(Short.parseShort(str));
                    initialPoint = Short.parseShort(str);
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    indicesList.add(Short.parseShort(str));
                    previousUpdated = Short.parseShort(str);
                } else if (i == 3 || i == 4) {
                    indicesList.add(previousUpdated);
                    indicesList.add(Short.parseShort(str));
                    previousUpdated = Short.parseShort(str);
                } else if (i == 5) {
                    indicesList.add(previousUpdated);
                    indicesList.add(initialPoint);
                }

            }
            updateVerticesListToArray(indicesList);
            drawShape(gl);

        }
    }
```

**THis is my Renderer class**

```
package com.view9.stoddart.opengl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.view9.stoddart.model.OpenGlRoofObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class StoddartNewRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private Context mContext;


    public float mAngleX = 0.0f;
    public float mAngleY = 0.0f;
    public float mAngleZ = 0.0f;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;
    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.6f;

    private OpenGlRoofObject roofObject;
    GL10 glForShape;
    RoofShape roofShape;

    public StoddartNewRenderer(Context context, OpenGlRoofObject roofObject) {
        mContext = context;
        this.roofObject = roofObject;
        roofShape = new RoofShape(roofObject);

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
//        Log.d("####","draw frame called");
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleX, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleY, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleZ, 0, 0, 1);


        // Set line color to black
        gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
//        gl.glColorMask(true, false, false, true);

        roofShape.drawShape(gl);

        //testing
        glForShape = gl;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig config) {
        Log.d("####", "surface created");
        gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// Enabled the vertex buffer for writing and to be used during rendering.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (height == 0) height = 1;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float aspect = (float) width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-aspect, aspect, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Log.d("####", "surface is changed");
    }

    public void drawSelectedShape(float x, float y) {
        ArrayList<CoOrdinatesModel> flashingPoint = new ArrayList<>();
        flashingPoint.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(x - 0.1f, y, 0f));
        flashingPoint.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(x, y + 0.1f, 0f));
        flashingPoint.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(x + 0.1f, y, 0f));
        flashingPoint.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(x, y - 0.1f, 0f));
        roofShape.setFlashingPointTOCordinatelist(glForShape, flashingPoint);

    }


}
```

**This is my GLSurfaceview class**

```
package com.view9.stoddart.opengl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

/**
 * Created by view9 on 10/12/15.
 */
public class StoddartOpenGlSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    StoddartNewRenderer renderer;

    public StoddartOpenGlSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }


    public StoddartOpenGlSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void showRenderer(StoddartNewRenderer renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
//        return renderer.onTouchEvent(event);
        float x = e.getX() / 100;
        float y = e.getY() / 100;
        Log.d("position", "x-axis: " + x + " y-axis: " + y);
        renderer.drawSelectedShape(x, y);
        requestRender();
        return true;

    }
}
```

**And this is the activity where I've set glsurfaceview**
data are fetched from the api which is in xml format I've parsed data well and stored it as a roofobject.

```
package com.view9.stoddart.activities;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.view9.stoddart.ApiCallConfiguration.ServerConfig;
import com.view9.stoddart.ApiCallConfiguration.WebService;
import com.view9.stoddart.R;
import com.view9.stoddart.fragment.ItemsSelectFragment;
import com.view9.stoddart.model.OpenGlRoofObject;
import com.view9.stoddart.model.SelectItemsDto;
import com.view9.stoddart.opengl.StoddartNewRenderer;
import com.view9.stoddart.opengl.StoddartOpenGlSurfaceView;
import com.view9.stoddart.utills.AppController;
import com.view9.stoddart.utills.Cache;
import com.view9.stoddart.utills.CustomDialogs;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by view9 on 6/8/15.
 */
public class DrawingFlashingActivity extends BaseActivity {
    DrawingFlashingActivity instance = null;

    public DrawingFlashingActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }


    OpenGlRoofObject roofObject;


    private LinearLayout gridLayout, flashingDiagramLayout;

//    StoddartRenderer renderer;
    StoddartNewRenderer renderer;
    StoddartOpenGlSurfaceView stoddartOpenGlSurfaceView;
    Response.Listener<String> response;
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
    Dialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = DrawingFlashingActivity.this;
        roofObject = Cache.cachedRoofObject;
        iniitilizeUiComponent();
        stoddartOpenGlSurfaceView = (StoddartOpenGlSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.opengl_surface_view);
        renderer = new StoddartNewRenderer(getInstance(), roofObject);
        stoddartOpenGlSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
        stoddartOpenGlSurfaceView.showRenderer(renderer);
        gettingServerResponse();
        pDialog = CustomDialogs.progressDialog(getInstance(), AppController.LOADING);
    }

    private void gettingServerResponse() {
        response = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                Log.d("response", s);
                pDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject nodeObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    Boolean status = nodeObject.getBoolean("success");
                    int code = nodeObject.getInt("code");
                    if (code == 1 && status) {
                        Cache.FLASHING_TYPE = s;
                        parseFlashingType(s);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
                volleyError.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

    private void parseFlashingType(String s) {
        try {
            ArrayList<SelectItemsDto> itemslist = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONObject nodeObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray dataArray = nodeObject.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                String type = dataArray.get(i).toString();
                itemslist.add(new SelectItemsDto("i", type, false, false));
            }

            ItemsSelectFragment alertdFragment = new ItemsSelectFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title", "Choose Flashing Type");
            bundle.putBoolean("isSingleSelect", true);

            bundle.putSerializable("itemsList", (Serializable) itemslist);
            alertdFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            alertdFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Alert Dialog Fragment");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String getToolbarTitle() {
        return "Flashing";
    }

    @Override
    public int getResourceLayout() {
        return R.layout.layout_flashing_measure_activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getActivityId() {
        return 8;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stoddartOpenGlSurfaceView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        stoddartOpenGlSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    private void iniitilizeUiComponent() {
        gridLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l_gridLayout);
        gridLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        flashingDiagramLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.flashing_diagram_layout);
        flashingDiagramLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setListeners();
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        ivTick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Cache.FLASHING_TYPE != "") {
                    parseFlashingType(Cache.FLASHING_TYPE);
                } else {
                    pDialog.show();
                    WebService.getFlashingType(response, errorListener, ServerConfig.GET_FLASHING_TYPE_URL);
                }

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Writing these codes I can successfully draw a shape as shown in the diagram. The diagram shown is of a roof. My question is that I want to add a circle on touching the shape; there may be multiple circles, e.g. if I touch on say(1,2,1) co-ordinate, the circle should be added to that point again. If I touch another point, the next circle should be added to that point and so on... This is also shown in the second image.

I've wasted 3 days doing this but didn't find any solutions; what I've tried to do in this code so far is: whenever I touch the view I calculate the value of x and y and passed to this method `setFlashingPointTOCordinatelist()` which is defined in the `RoofShape` class.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. And please keep in mind that I am very new to this opengl. I can draw this image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLv2D.png).

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwPOD.jpg) is the image what I want to do on touch over the shape.